# Writing Science Fiction when the writer is from a society which is not very scientifically advanced

Tags: technique, science-fiction, setting

When a writer belongs to a society which is not very scientifically advanced, creating organizations like NASA and characters like indigenous Scientists would look terribly out of place. And, if the writer decides to set his story in any advanced society, his characters might look contrived, because he might not be fully aware of their culture. How does the Writer break this deadlock?

Comment: Some clarifications: (1) Can you research how scientists work in other societies? (2) Do you have ideas of how scientists in _your_ society work, even if that's not how scientists work elsewhere?

Comment: @Standback (1) Yes, I can certainly do that. (2) I have interacted with a few of them and I know their research procedures fairly well.

Comment: Umm ... so what's the question? If you are setting a story in a society where there are no scientists ... then don't put any scientists there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically 5 stages that worlds go through as they develop (read more here: http://www.bang2write.com/2013/05/top-5-tips-for-writing-science-fiction-by-robert-grant.html) and some the best sci-fi takes place in the period of transition from one stage to the next. By choosing to set your story between two world stages you get to watch both society and individuals struggle with change, you can bend the rules because they are not fully established and you can compare and contrast what was and what will be. If you can't decide when to set your story then it sounds to me like you should choose a transitional period and write from there.

Comment: It seems pretty glib to say that all worlds or even a "typical" world go through those 5 stages. Who says? This is obviously the writer's 20,000 foot overview of Earth history for the first 4 and his prediction for the 5th. One could easily quibble with his description as being accurate for Earth, but even if we grant it for our world, how do we know that other planets must, inevitably go through the same 5 stages?